# Is there a way to include OpenID as a drop down option in the contribution lis? or Is there a way to convert OpenID to external identifier?

Tags: import, contributions

When I imported contacts, I listed their identification number as OpenID. Now, I am trying up import the contacts' contributions. Along with their name, amount, date of donation, I am including their OpenID.....yet, the drop down options in the import contributions does not include OpenID...therefore, the import will not function.

a) Is there a way to include OpenID as a drop down option in the contribution list? 
if not...
b) Is there a way to convert OpenID to external identifier?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the name of the drop down list that you want to include it in?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of the specific name  - but the drop down list appears in: import contributions, match fields (step 2 of 4), Matching CiviCRM Field (this is where the drop down list appears). does this info help? thanks for thinking about this.

Comment: Hi @JohnFF I'm sorry, I forgot to add in your name to my response yesterday - here it is again -     
I'm not exactly sure of the specific name - but the drop down list appears in: import contributions, match fields (step 2 of 4), Matching CiviCRM Field (this is where the drop down list appears). does this info help? thanks for thinking about this.

Comment: What are the options that are available?

Answer (score 1):

a) Is there a way to include OpenID as a drop down option in the contribution list?

If you created a custom data field called "OpenID", you need to make sure the field can be used for contributions and that it is marked as searchable for it to appear in the list of fields when mapping contributions for import,

**BUT**

if memory serves me correctly, the system will require either an internal or external contact ID when importing contributions, so...

b) Is there a way to convert OpenID to external identifier?

Since you already imported the contacts, you can export all contacts being sure to include the OpenID and internal contact ID fields, then the update can be done in one of three ways - which ever you find easiest:

1. Use the import contacts wizard to update all contacts mapping the OpenID to the external contact ID field using the internal ID as the link, **OR**
2. Use a vlookup in csv to match the internal contact ID to the OpenID in your contribution data import file, and then import your contributions based on the internal contact ID, **OR**
3. Use an SQL statement that will copy the OpenID to the external contact ID field by contact ID directly in the database

Hope this helps,
Tamar